# How to recompile WinSCP without Finalizer

Tags: c++, winscp, winscp-net

I need to use WinSCP in a SqlServer context (yes, I know this is not a good idea).

The problem with WinSCP in a Sql Server context is that Finalizers are not allowed.

I know C#, but not C++, so am looking for some guidance on how to proceed with removing the Finalizers.

Greg

Comment: Are you sure that you need to remove finalizers, were there any, to make the code run under SQL server? Isn't it just that SQL server CLR does not guarantee finalizers to be run?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, as I tried to load it in.  As soon as you try to load, Sql Server scans the dll and it gives that messge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinSCP itself (not the C# WinSCP .NET assembly wrapper) is pure WinAPI C++ application, not Managed C++. So there are no finalizers.

Comment: Well, I removed the C# finalizers, but then Sql Server started complaining about using PInvoke.  So am going to try something different at this time.  But thanks very much for your attention to this matter.

Comment: Makes sense, but there's nothing you can do about PInvoke's.